# expect(...).toHaveStyleRule is not a function

Tags: jestjs, emotion

I've been trying to set up `jest-enzyme` according to [the official guide](https://emotion.sh/docs/jest-emotion#snapshot-serializer), but Jest doesn't seem to register the `jest-enzyme` plugin.

I've abbreviated some of the following snippets.

### package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^10.0.27",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "jest-emotion": "^10.0.27",
  }
}
```

---

### jest.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  snapshotSerializers: ['jest-emotion'],
  // ...
}
```

I've also tried to register it in my `setupTests.js` file (the same file in which I configure Enzyme), but to no avail.

---

Here is the terminal output when I run the tests.

```sh
    # output

    TypeError: expect(...).toHaveStyleRule is not a function

       8 |              const wrapper = mount(<Container />);
       9 | 
    > 10 |              expect(wrapper).toHaveStyleRule('max-width', '192rem');
         |                              ^
      11 |      });
      12 | });
      13 | 

      at Object.toHaveStyleRule (__tests__/components/layout/container.test.jsx:10:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

Totally ignored the part in the docs about [custom matchers](https://emotion.sh/docs/jest-emotion#custom-matchers)

Comment: Link seems to have changed to https://emotion.sh/docs/@emotion/jest#gatsby-focus-wrapper